# Order with a has_many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have `Articles` that have_many `Metrics`. I wish to order the `Articles` by a specific Metric.value when Metric.name = "score". (`Metric` records various article stats as 'name' and 'value' pairs. An Article can have multiple metrics, and even multiple 'scores', although I'm only interested in ordering by the most recent.)

```
class Article
  has_many :metrics

class Metric
  #  name       :string(255)
  #  value      :decimal(, )
  belongs_to :article
```

I'm struggling to write a scope to do this - any ideas? Something like this?

```
scope :highest_score, joins(:metrics).order('metrics.value DESC')
                      .where('metrics.name = "score"')
```

**UPDATE:**

- An article may have many "scores" stored in the `metrics` table (as they are calculated weekly/monthly/yearly etc.) but I'm only interested in using the first-found (most recent) "score" for any one article. The `Metric` model has a default_scope that ensures DESCending ordering.
- Fixed typo on quote location for 'metrics.value DESC'.
- Talking to my phone-a-friend uber rails hacker, it looks likely I need a raw SQL query for this. Now I'm in way over my head... (I'm using Postgres if that helps.)

Thanks!

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to Erwin's great SQL query suggestion I have a raw SQL query that works:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   articles a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_id)
          article_id, value
   FROM   metrics m
   WHERE  name = 'score'
   ORDER  BY article_id, date_created DESC
   ) m ON m.article_id = a.id
ORDER  BY m.value DESC;

article_list_by_desc_score = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Which gives an array of hashes representing article data (but not article objects??).

*Follow-up question:*

Any way of translating this back into an activerecord query for Rails? (so I can then use it in a scope)

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

In case anyone is looking for the final ActiveRecord query - many thanks to Mattherick who helped me in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417112/converting-an-sql-query-to-a-rails-arel-query). The final working query is:

```
scope :highest_score, joins(:metrics).where("metrics.name"
      => "score").order("metrics.value desc").group("metrics.article_id", 
      "articles.id", "metrics.value", "metrics.date_created")
      .order("metrics.date_created desc")
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: order('metrics.value' DESC) . Shouldn't the desc be within the quotes? like order('metrics.value DESC'). Anyways what error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks manoj - the DESC/quote thing was a typo. The error I get is "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: column "score" does not exist" so a syntax error on my part as "score" is the value of the "name" column of the "metrics" table.

Comment: What do you mean by "poor mans noSQL"? Are you using AR's key/value store? Postgres hstore?

Comment: Thanks for asking cpuguy83. Ahh, I should move that noSQL reference as it confuses the question. Really, I'm just using the Metrics table in a standard Postgres database with 'names' and 'values'. The 'name' column is conceptually like a key, but that's it's only similarity with noSQL.

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL you'll probably need to post table definitions with sample data to http://sqlfiddle.com/ (PostgreSQL) and link to the result here.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query could work like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   article a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_id)
          article_id, value
   FROM   metrics m
   WHERE  name = 'score'
   ORDER  BY article_id, date_created DESC
   ) m ON m.metrics_id = a.metrics_id
ORDER  BY m.value DESC;
```

**First**, retrieve the "most recent" `value` for `name = 'score'` per article in the subquery `m`. More explanation for the used technique in this related answer:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

You seem to fall victim to a very basic misconception though:

> but I'm only interested in using the first-found (most recent) "score"
>   for any one article. The Metric model has a default_scope that ensures DESCending ordering.

There is **no "natural order"** in a table. In a `SELECT`, you need to `ORDER BY` well defined criteria. For the purpose of this query I am assuming a column `metrics.date_created`. If you have nothing of the sort, you have *no way* to define "most recent" and are forced to fall back to an arbitrary pick from multiple qualifying rows:

```
   ORDER  BY article_id
```

This is *not* reliable. Postgres will pick a row as it choses. May change with any update to the table or any change in the query plan.

**Next**, `LEFT JOIN` to the the table `article` and `ORDER BY value`. `NULL` sorts last, so articles without qualifying value go last.

Note: some not-so-smart ORMs (and I am afraid Ruby's ActiveRecord is one of them) use the non-descriptive and non-distinctive **`id`** as name for the primary key. You'll have to adapt to your actual column names, which you didn't provide.

#### Performance

Should be decent. This is a "simple" query as far as Postgres is concerned. A partial multicolumn index on table `metrics` would make it faster:

```
CREATE INDEX metrics_some_name_idx ON metrics(article_id, date_created)
WHERE name = 'score';
```

Columns in this order. In PostgreSQL 9.2+ you could add the column value to make index-only scans possible:

```
CREATE INDEX metrics_some_name_idx ON metrics(article_id, date_created, value)
WHERE name = 'score';
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin, great info. My Metrics table is by default ordered by descending date_created (it has all the usual timestamps). I'll give the raw sql a try - thanks!

Comment: Erwin, thanks again. I've had a bit of a play with the SQL you gave, and after a bit of massaging have the query working. Though I can't work out how to use this in a scope in model — see the update to my question.

Comment: @dj.: I am not an expert with Ruby. But I added some more info as far as Postgres is concerned.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I had one of those index's already setup, and will add the other. Thanks again. You get the gong!