# Converting an SQL query to a Rails AREL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have a working SQL query thanks to the help of [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) in my earlier question '[Order with a has_many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382606/order-with-a-has-many-relationship)'.

How would I turn this SQL into an ActiveRecords or AREL query for use in a scope?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   articles a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_id)
          article_id, value
   FROM   metrics m
   WHERE  name = 'score'
   ORDER  BY article_id, date_created DESC
   ) m ON m.article_id = a.id
ORDER  BY m.value DESC;
```

The closest I have come is with a friends help...

```
scope :highest_score, select("articles.*").joins("LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
      DISTINCT ON (article_id) article_id, value FROM metrics WHERE name = 
      'score' ORDER  BY article_id, date_created DESC) ON metrics.article_id = 
      articles.id").order("metrics.value DESC")
```

...which gives me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError:
      ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

**UPDATE:**

My earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382606/order-with-a-has-many-relationship) has a complete description of the relevant schema and query. But basically `Articles have_many Metrics`, and a `Metric` has a `name` and a `value`. My query orders `Articles` by the *highest* `value` of the *most recent* `Metric` with `name = 'score'`.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Mattherick for pointing me in the correct direction! His query works on SQLite, but due to postgresql's (appropriate) intolerance for ambiguity, the final working scope is:

```
scope :highest_score, joins(:metrics).where("metrics.name" => "score")
      .order("metrics.value desc").group("metrics.article_id", 
      "articles.id", "metrics.value", "metrics.date_created")
      .order("metrics.date_created desc")
```

The SO question which Matherick referred to in his comments explains the problem here — and why sqlite is at fault for accepting ambiguous queries rather than postgresql for refusing. Good example for me of the benefit of using the *same* database for local development as for production.

Comment: how does your schema and associations look like? with this information it is easier to try your query ;). without more information maybe this works: scope :highest_score, lambda { Article.all.includes(:metrics).where(:name => "score").order("article_id desc and date_created desc") }

Comment: Thanks Mattherick! I didn't want to double post the info, as my schema and associations are described in this first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382606/order-with-a-has-many-relationship — but basically Articles has_many Metrics, and a Metric has a name and a value. My query orders Articles by the highest value of the most recent Metric with name = 'score'. Thanks for any help you can give! dj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :highest_score, lambda { Article.joins(:metrics).where("metrics.name" => "score").order("metrics.value").group(:article_id).order("metrics.article_id desc").order("metrics.date_created desc") }

end
```

Comment: Thanks Mettherick. Unfortunately I get this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column metrics.score does not exist. LINE 1: ...P BY article_id ORDER BY metrics.article_id desc, metrics.sc... though I think your query misses a few pieces, namely the ordering of the Articles by the Metric.value for Metric.name = "score". Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Updated my answer, but I am not shure anymore :). I don´t get a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR. I simple tried it out with sqlite3 on my local machine.

Comment: As I see now you are getting a PostgressError, maybe this question could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418504/pgerror-in-group-by-clause

Comment: Thanks Mathherick. That link helps explain the problem and lead me to the solution using your query. Thanks again! ANS: scope :highest_score, lambda { Article.joins(:metrics).where("metrics.name" => "score").order("metrics.value desc").group("metrics.article_id", "articles.id", "metrics.value", "metrics.date_created").order("metrics.date_created desc") }

Comment: Also, the lambda isn't needed (I think only needed for dynamic scopes where you are passing in a variable) so I removed it.

Comment: Yes I think the lambda is not necessary in rails 3.2, but rails 4 you will get a deprecation warning, or directly an error, if I´m not mistaken.